# Convert date yyyyMMdd to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss format with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have date in XML as

```
<TODAYDATE>20160509<TODAYDATE>
```

I want to convert it using xsl

```
<com2:TodayDat>
    <xsl:value-of select="TODAYDATE" />
</com2:TodayDat>
```

but I want it in format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss using some function etc in xsl. 
It should show as 2016-05-09T00:00:00

Please help

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Use the `substring()` function - e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="substring(TODAYDATE, 1, 4)" />` to extract the year, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(TODAYDATE, 1, 4)" />-<xsl:value-of select="substring(TODAYDATE, 5, 2)" />-<xsl:value-of select="substring(TODAYDATE, 7, 2)" /> T00:00:00
```

Online output:http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAN/2